Maptiler Geocoding make markers interactive
I have a circle in my map. I want the marker from the MapTiler Geocoding search to be clickable and/or colored differently to demonstrate if it is inside the circle or not.
The code I have below works. It's mostly straight from their site, but I cannot make the marker one that can be clicked or changed at all. Or if I can retrieve the lat/long directly from the search, but anything I've found has not returned any results.
I've tried some other free geocoders but even common addresses could not be found and I need it to be able to find practically anything.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm open to other geocoders but they need to be free and find a broad number of addresses.


const key = 'MYKEY';
const map = L.map('map').setView([35.992256, -83.925643], 10);

const layer = L.tileLayer(`https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets-v2/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=${key}`, {
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1,
  minZoom: 1,
  attribution: "\u003ca href=\"https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u0026copy; MapTiler\u003c/a\u003e \u003ca href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u0026copy; OpenStreetMap contributors\u003c/a\u003e",
  crossOrigin: true
}).addTo(map);

var markercenter = L.marker([0, 0]).addTo(map);
markercenter.bindPopup("CenterOfCircle").openPopup();

var circle = L.circle([0, 0], {
  color: 'blue',
  fillColor: 'blue',
  fillOpacity: 0.1,
  radius: 40233.6
}).addTo(map);

var search = L.control.maptilerGeocoding({
  apiKey: key,
  flyTo: false,
}).addTo(map);
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.maptiler.com/maptiler-geocoding-control/v1.3.3/leaflet.umd.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.maptiler.com/maptiler-geocoding-control/v1.3.3/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="map"></div>




I'm a little confused what you're asking as the marker in your example already has a popup on it? If you want a custom popup, then their documentation covers that: https://docs.maptiler.com/sdk-js/examples/set-popup/. That also covers how to make a custom marker.

No, I would like the marker that appears with the geocoding search to be interactable in the same manner as the one I already have.

Update [2024-10-18]:
As of version 2.0.0 the library now supports asked feature. Please see the example. (The approach will work also in non-svelte applications.)
Original Answer (for reference):
At the time of writing, the library did not support this feature.
Unfortunately it is not trivial to fully customize the marker in the current version of MapTiler Geocoding Control without lot of custom code (by writing your own Controller and derived Leaflet geocoding control). You can now easily only set the marker properties - for example to change its icon, by setting marker or showResultMarkers control option.
Regarding getting the lat/lon - you can listen event response on the Map but there is a plan to refactor it as it is currently poorly designed.
